# Транслитерация немецкой фамилии Schikorr

Tags: транслитерация

Набрел в Вики на "[реакцию Шикора](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schikorr_reaction)". Или "реакцию Шикорра"? Как правильнее транслитерировать немецкую фамилию Schikorr?

Поиск по "коррозия Шикорр" и "коррозия Шикор" показывает, что оба варианта используются.

Comment: Вы термины "транскрипция" и "транслитерация" употребляете случайным образом?

Comment: @behemothus - да, мне сейчас это неважно. Интересно, как транс.. (посмотрел) литерировать фамилию.

Comment: Ну если не важно, так разберитесь сначала, а потом уже спрашивайте. Транскрипция может отличаться от транслитерации.

Comment: @behemothus - транслитерация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имена собственные при перенесении в другой язык не подчиняются каким-то единым правилам. "Как надо" вам никто не скажет, пока не будет единой словарной фиксации. На письме логично, наверное, оставить два Р, поскольку это не противоречит русской фонетике. Но с другой стороны, зачем тащить в русский то, чего нет в оригинальном произношении? Так что расхождения в источниках понятны.

> @behemothus - транслитерация.

Транслитерация - с двумя Р, тут и думать нечего. По определению. Транслитерация - передача знаков одной письменности знаками другой. 
Вопрос в том, будет ли при заимствовании имени собственного использоваться этот принцип.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Просто подумал - как назвать статью, если решу в руВики сделать перевод.

Comment: @CopperKettle В Вики принято давать все варианты написания. Под каким конкретно именем будет статья - не критично.